# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'HashMap<String, dynamic>' Dart

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, hashmap

I am having a response below

```
[
    {
        "name": "Kamchatka",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "kamchatka@mail.com",
        "index": 1,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Valjakutse",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "valjakutse@mail.com",
        "index": 2,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    },
    {
        "name": "Shipment",
        "about": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborumnumquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident similique accusantium nemo autem.",
        "email": "shipment@mail.com",
        "index": 3,
        "picture": "https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/"
    }
]
```

I am having a Future which is async and should take the response and convert it into a List of HashMap like below

```
  Future<List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>> _fetchUsersListHashMap() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonkeeper.com/b/XBCA"));

      late List<HashMap<String, dynamic>> responseList;

      responseList = List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(response.body));
    
      String stringList = jsonEncode(responseList);

      log("FetchUsersListHashMap $stringList");

      return responseList;

    } catch (e) {

      log("FetchUsersListHashMapException $e");

      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

When i call _fetchUsersListHashMap i am getting below error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'HashMap<String, dynamic>'
```

I have even tried changing the way i am assigning responseList to

```
responseList = json.decode(response.body);
```

But its not assigning the list of HashMap with the response from the url

Below is how i did it in java its just that i cant be able to replicate the same concept in flutter

```
  List<HashMap<String, Object>> responseList = new Gson().fromJson(response,
                                new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {
                                }.getType());
```

Comment: Use just `Map` instead of writing `HashMap`. `LinkedHashMap` is not the same as `HashMap` but in the end, you probably don't care about the internal implementation of the `Map`, so just use the interface instead of more specific classes.

Comment: there is a very specific reason i am not using Map because the response may contain keys with null values and Map wont accept that, i have been able to do it in hava using gson and type token but gson currently does not have null safety. @julemand101 Below is how i did it in jave i just want someone who can replicate the same concept in flutter      List<HashMap<String, Object>> responseList = new Gson().fromJson(response,
                                new TypeToken<List<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {
                                }.getType());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<List<HashMap<String, dynamic>>> _fetchUsersListHashMap() async {
 try {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonkeeper.com/b/XBCA"));

  final decoded = json.decode(response.body);

  final responseList = decoded
    .map<HashMap<String, dynamic>>((e) => HashMap<String, dynamic>.from(e))
    .toList();

  String stringList = jsonEncode(responseList);

  log("FetchUsersListHashMap $stringList");

  return responseList;
} catch (e) {
  log("FetchUsersListHashMapException $e");

  rethrow;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  List<HashMap<String, dynamic>> responseList = [];
  List jsonList = List.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
  jsonList.forEach((element) {
    responseList.add(HashMap.from(Map.from(element)));
  });
```

Comment: How can i print the responseList to see its contents

Comment: `print(responseList)` should work.